# Implementing generic linkedlist add method java

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to implement the add method for the linkedlist , it should take any data type, but I am kind of lost and is not working, any help will be appreciated.

```
 public class LinkedList <T>extends AbstractList  {

 private class Node {

    T data;
    Node next;

    Node(T data, Node next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    Node(T data) {
        this(data, null);
    }
}
Node first;
Node last;

public LinkedList() {
    first = null;
    last = null;
}

@Override
public boolean add(T item) {

    Node newNode = new Node((T)item);

    if (isEmpty()) {
        first = newNode;
        last = first;
        return true;
    }

    last.next = newNode;
    last = null;
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Is something not working? What is the problem?

Comment: `last = null;` looks to be incorrect. `last = newNode;` maybe?
Also you should genericise Node

Comment: `last = newNode` and `last.next = null`

Comment: +1 to the above comments, also consider peeking into `java.util.LinkedList` implementation for hints.

Answer (score 1):

You don't tell us your concrete problem, so we can't fix it, only guess.

One issue I see though is that you extend `AbstractList` as a raw (nongeneric) type - your declaration should be instead

```
public class LinkedList<T> extends AbstractList<T>  { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
last.next = newNode;
last = newNode;
```

Be careful that you understand why.

Before you add the new node, `last` is a reference to the last entry in the list.

What you want to do is to point **its** `next` reference to this new node.

The second line then updates `last` to refer to this new one too.